# Random Freezing

Tags: 12.04, freeze

For several months I've been experiencing random freezing (usually once or twice a day) and have yet to find out what the problem is or how to fix it. The symptoms always are:

- Mouse and keyboard don't work
- Screen freezes
- If there was sound playing, the last second of it is repeated over and over
- about 5% of the time it will fix itself within a few minutes

Comment: just curious to know a fresh install/upgraded/beta upgrade ? what kind of environment you having now  ?

Comment: Are you using nouveau with an nvidia card? The nouveau driver can do that. Try to ssh into your computer after it is frozen to see if it was a hard lockup or an X server lockup.

Comment: Hi guys I experience the same behavior (before on 11.04,11.10 now on 12.04) on my toshiba portege D600. It seems worse when I am doing backup to a usb disk. Mostly it happens when watching video with firefox or chrome. The computer is dead, no ssh logins possible during freeze,one other thing on my machine the fan start spinning, could be a cpu 100% issue, but even the light for caps lock don't toggle any more. Havn't found any clue to solve this so far.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: For anyone experiencing this or a similar situation, [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes) may help.